# Extracting nested xml tags (not its attributes or values or even contents.)

Tags: html, xml, perl

Hi Folks out there i have a real trouble to get the xml tag out of it while its nested. And i need your help to find the starting tag and closing tag from an xml file while its nested ? using Perl script (either regex or modules..anything is ok) but only perl

**NOTE: I need to number the tag and strictly i dont need the contents inside the tag.

Tried to copy epsilon because it shows me the correct closing tag when i select the starting tag. But i cant.**

Th sample pasted below is a small snippet but i need code for any number of nesting

```
sample Tag:
<mrow><mrow><mrow>....<mi>K<\mi>...<\mrow><mi><\mi><\mrow><\mrow>

expected output:

<mrow1><\mrow1>
<mrow2><\mrow2>
<mrow3><\mrow3>
```

Comment: [XMLLibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm).  Happy coding.  If you run into trouble ask, about _your code_.

Comment: Here people normally post their code, describing specific problems they have with it. This is not a good place to simply ask for someone to write code for you.

Comment: Also - without some sample (valid) XML, it's hard to even do that. But with XML::Twig you can rename your tags. Rearranging the tree structure (e.g. unrolling nesting) is somewhat harder though, so we need some clearer explanation. Sample input and output is a good start for that. XML::Twig lets you cut and paste elements, which sounds like it could be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a **Perl XML/XPath library**.

XML is not a regular language, so that regex would not suffice in the general case. Attempting to write new code to extract tags from an XML document would, in the end, come down to rewriting a basic (that is, not necessarily fully conformant) XML parser from scratch.

One of the reasons why XML usage is so widespread is that it is a W3C standard, so that there are a lot of existing conformant parsers out there, which spares the time and effort of writing new parsers. Some parsers will expose the document to the host language (e.g., DOM), some will come with XPath included, which makes it even easier.

I hope this helps!